# Why I get the error 502

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am using codeIgniter

```
public function add()
{

    if(!$this->session->userdata('id') || !$this->session->userdata('email'))
    {
        echo "please enter before";
        exit();
    }
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $organization = $this->input->post('organization');
    $adress = $this->input->post('adress');
    $responsable = $this->input->post('responsable');
    $doljnost = $this->input->post('doljnost');
    $rab_tel = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('rab_tel'));
    $mob_tel = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('mob_tel'));
    $desc = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('desc'));
    $uslovia = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('uslovia'));
    $ocobennosti = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('ocobennosti'));
    $coupons = $this->input->post('coupons');
    $discount = $this->input->post('discount');
    $category = $this->input->post('category');
    $days = $this->input->post('days');


    if(empty($discount) || empty($adress) || empty($mob_tel) || empty($discount))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'fill the inputs');
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('user_add', null, true);
        $this->load->view('layout', $data);
    }
    else
    {
                $this->db->query('INSERT INTO user_adds (`organization`, `adress`,
                `responsable`, `doljnost`, `rab_tel`,
                `mob_tel`,`desc`, `uslovia`, `ocobennosti`, `coupons`, `category`, `end`, `user_id`) VALUES
                ("'.$organization.'", "'.$adress.'", "'.$responsable.'",
                "'.$doljnost.'", "'.$rab_tel.'", "'.$mob_tel.'",
                "'.$desc.'", "'.$uslovia.'", "'.$ocobennosti.'",
                "'.$coupons.'", "'.$category.'", NOW() + INTERVAL '.$days.' DAY, "'.$user_id.'")');
            redirect('/');
    }
}
```

after this method is executed, then when i pass to another page, its show me this error

502 Bad Gateway

The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

What i am doing wrong??

the session library is automatic loaded, i am just passing to this method and it is not nessesary to submit

Comment: I am having a 502 bad gateway issue as well. I narrowed it down to the point that it has a relation with cart library. Have you found the solution / work around to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just putted local variables and an insert into mysql db. Never touched something that make calls to HTTP(client) or that accept HTTP (server).

The only thing that appears to be somehow related to HTTP is the call of a local function called redirect.
May be the problem is there.

502 Bad Gateway is generally returned by a reverse proxy when the local HTTP delivery to the backend server fails.
Try to comment out redirect("/") to see what happens

Comment: Any idea why it's making a HTTP call? Facing a very similar issue, and haven't found any other information on anyone seeing the same problem. I'm guessing it's to do with the redirect function as opposed to storing session data.